# Array is remain still empty while fetching coordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have array of country names and i want to get coordinates of them and store into another array. after this function my longitudes and latitudes arrays are **remains still empty**. do you have idea what is problem here ? i can't understand.

My Code is :

```
    - (void)geocode {
    NSString *strcountry=[[NSString alloc]init];
    countryLati=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    countryLongi=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    countryName =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bahrain",@"Bangladesh",@"Bhutan",@"China",@"Georgia",@"Hong Kong",nil ];
    int count=[countryName count];



    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        strcountry=[countryName objectAtIndex:i];


    [SVGeocoder geocode:strcountry
             completion:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

                 //NSLog(@"placemarks = %@", placemarks);

                 CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                 CLLocation *location = place.location;
                 CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = location.coordinate;

                 NSString *tempLati=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%g",coord.latitude];
                 NSString *tempLongi=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%g",coord.longitude];
                 NSLog(@"-------------------------");
                 NSLog(@"Country : %@",strcountry);
                 NSLog(@"Latitude : %@ ",tempLati);
                 NSLog(@"Longitude : %@ ",tempLongi);

                 [countryLati addObject:tempLati];
                 [countryLongi addObject:tempLongi];

             }];


    }

    NSLog(@"%d",[countryName count]);
    NSLog(@"%d ",[countryLati count]);
    NSLog(@"%d ",[countryLongi count]);      


}
```

Comment: Usual question; are you sure the array `!= nil`?

Comment: i have not add any object before for loop. I have just allocate both array at starting of above method.

Comment: are you sure, the completion block is giving place marks array..? and can u show us the Log which is printed..

Comment: both arrays are goes nil after for loop even my arrays are global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accept Nuzhat Zari solution. Below is the code without using blocks and 3rd party Libraries. Its just a suggetion and showing you one more way of getting location details.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

this URL has a good documentation for Google API.

```
- (void)geocode 
{
NSString *strcountry=[[NSString alloc]init];
countryLati=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
countryLongi=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
countryName =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bahrain",@"Bangladesh",@"Bhutan",@"China",@"Georgia",@"Hong Kong",nil ];
int count=[countryName count];



for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    strcountry=[countryName objectAtIndex:i];


    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", strCountry];
    NSString* webStringURL = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Location String = %@", locationString);
    NSArray *receivedGoogleData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
    searchTermLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[receivedGoogleData objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue] longitude:[[receivedGoogleData objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue]];

    [countryLati addObject:[[receivedGoogleData objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue]];
    [countryLongi addObject:[[receivedGoogleData objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue]];

}

NSLog(@"%d",[countryName count]);
NSLog(@"%d ",[countryLati count]);
NSLog(@"%d ",[countryLongi count]);      
}
```

@Mahesh Dhapa : Try this one, From my perspective, I feel this is easy than your way of SVGeoCoder, because no need to extra importing of SVGeocoder classes. BTW, SVGeocoder is simple. But, This is also straight forward without using 3rd party libraries.

You get response from Google like this 
200,1,23.8954,34.5478

In which,
200 - Success
1 - Accuracy
23.8954 - Latitude of location
34.5478 - Longitude of location

You can also get this in JSON and XML Format with extra clear information, But you need to decode them to Dictionary from JSON and XML format to use them.

**Example JSON Format :**

```
{
  "name": "Bahrain",
  "Status": {
    "code": 200,
    "request": "geocode"
  },
  "Placemark": [ {
    "id": "p1",
    "address": "Bahrain",
    "AddressDetails": {
   "Accuracy" : 1,
   "Country" : {
      "CountryName" : "Bahrain",
      "CountryNameCode" : "BH"
  }
},
    "ExtendedData": {
      "LatLonBox": {
        "north": 26.3240565,
        "south": 25.5798401,
        "east": 50.8228639,
        "west": 50.3781509
      }
    },
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": [ 50.5577000, 26.0667000, 0 ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

**Example XML Response :**

```
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
<Response>
<name>Bahrain</name>
<Status>
<code>200</code>
<request>geocode</request>
</Status>
<Placemark id="p1">
<address>Bahrain</address>
<AddressDetails xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0" Accuracy="1">
<Country>
<CountryNameCode>BH</CountryNameCode>
<CountryName>Bahrain</CountryName>
</Country>
</AddressDetails>
<ExtendedData>
<LatLonBox north="26.3240565" south="25.5798401" east="50.8228639" west="50.3781509"/>
</ExtendedData>
<Point>
<coordinates>50.5577000,26.0667000,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</Response>
</kml>
```

Comment: what is type of `searchTermLocation` ?

Comment: searchTermLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[receivedGoogleData objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue] longitude:[[receivedGoogleData objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue]];

Comment: It is CLLocation type..The statement itself shows it. But, anyway you need this line only if you want those coordinates in CLLocation format you need it. Otherwise, you can use just the raw latitude and longitudes from the response as I used below that line

Comment: Jitendra , Thanks a lot for your answer, its really useful for me. getting coordinates from this method is very easy and fast and its not taking more time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you want to change local variable in block you need to declare it as block, as follows:

```
    NSArray *stringsArray = @[ @"string 1",

                              @"String 21", 

                              @"string 12",

                              @"String 11",

                              @"Strîng 21", 

                              @"Striñg 21", 

                              @"String 02" ];

    NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

    __block NSUInteger orderedSameCount = 0;

     NSArray *diacriticInsensitiveSortArray = [stringsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id string1, id string2) {
      NSRange string1Range = NSMakeRange(0, [string1 length]);

    NSComparisonResult comparisonResult = [string1 compare:string2 options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch range:string1Range locale:currentLocale];

   if (comparisonResult == NSOrderedSame) {
       orderedSameCount++;
   }
    return comparisonResult;
}];

NSLog(@"diacriticInsensitiveSortArray: %@", diacriticInsensitiveSortArray);

NSLog(@"orderedSameCount: %d", orderedSameCount);
```

Edit:A statement from reference.

> A powerful feature of blocks is that they can modify variables in the
>   same lexical scope. You signal that a block can modify a variable
>   using the __block storage type modifier.

So you should declare countryLati and countryLongi as block storage.